# Using Google Docs OCR for other things on Android

Tags: android, ocr

I am thinking of capturing some text from documents using my android phone and was looking for an ideal OCR app on android. I just happened to read today that Google introduced OCR for scanning documents that can be edited in Google Docs. I was wondering if I could use the OCR for things other than converting the documents to Google Docs - say, like taking a picture of a certificate and capturing the names and dates of birth of the candidates or taking a photo of a license plate and be able to get the info as text that can be stored.

If anyone has an idea of how to achieve this on Android using Google's OCR, that would be great to know. I did read about Tesseract/Tesjeract but it seems very difficult to implement what I want using it - maybe I didnt fully understand how to use it through Java. Here's the link to the new app that uses OCR to scan documents - [Google Docs on Android](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs)

Answer (score 0):

We have tried Google Docs API a wile ago, but it is very weak in terms of accuracy. Looks like it is based on some outdated version of tesseract. I suppose you would get more accuracy if you try tesseract. However, you will need to manage special preprocessing of images taken by camera since they introduce additional challenges. Google Docs API does not have that.

On running Tesseract on Android look here:
[Using tesseract on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454848/using-tesseract-on-android)

Commertial alternative to tesseract for OCR on mobile phone:
http://www.abbyy.com/mobileocr/

However, if you are looking not into just capturing text, but also exptracting data, then you may need additional technology to parse text output. That means writing even more code. Or there is alternative to license existing commertial Data Capture API from ABBYY. That was already discussed here:

[Recognise text in certain position using the Iphone camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783422/recognise-text-in-certain-position-using-the-iphone-camera)

Disclaimer: I work for ABBYY

Answer (score -1):

You can use Google Docs (now called Google Drive) to OCR an image by uploading the image to Google Drive. Later you can pull this Google Document back as a text/rtf/doc/html file. This data now - you may use however you like in your app. This can be achieved directly without user intervention using Google Drive APIs. Here are some Google App API references:

To upload with OCR: see
[Fail to upload a image file into Google Doc via java api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170579/fail-to-upload-a-image-file-into-google-doc-via-java-api) with ?convert=true
To download a file from Google Drive:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#downloading_documents_and_files
`https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/Export?docID=__INSERT-ID__&exportFormat=txt&format=txt`

Beware there should be a quota in place to use the OCR service.