# Fail to upload a image file into Google Doc via java api

Tags: java, google-docs, google-docs-api

below is my code

```
DocsService client = new DocsService("testappv1");
client.setUserCredentials(username, password);
client.setProtocolVersion(DocsService.Versions.V2);
File file = new File("C:/test.jpg");
DocumentEntry newDocument = new DocumentEntry();
newDocument.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("test"));
String mimeType = DocumentListEntry.MediaType.fromFileName(file.getName()).getMimeType();
newDocument.setMediaSource(new MediaFileSource(file, mimeType));
newDocument = client.insert(destFolderUrl, newDocument);
```

the document was created successful, but it did not contain anything.

Comment: I assume its an empty text document thats created? did you want this? or did you want the file uploaded to be a plain image?

Comment: I wanna create a google-doc format document that just contain a image. Just like I direct drag a image file into google-doc.

Answer (score 3):

try the following

```
client.insert(new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full/?convert=false"), newDocument);
```

i think the `?convert=false` bit is important, not sure how you do that without the url

```
client.insert(new URL(destFolderUrl+ "?convert=false"), newDocument);
```

would hopefully work in your case

Comment: in my google doc setting, I set convert document into google format. if I add "convert=false" behind my URL, it will throw an error. `URL destFolderUrl = new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/folders/private/full/folderResourceId?convert=false");`

Comment: I think thats your problem, its trying to convert a jpeg when it doesn't know how to, you shouldn't have to.

Comment: so any sugestion? it was working fine, just recently got this problem.

Comment: This issue seems similar to the one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10195674/1106381). Can you try using the provided code snippet to upload your file?

Comment: hi Alain, thanks for your replay, actually I want google to convert my image, beacuse I need bring it down by document list api in future. I have not tried that code snippert yet. I do hope it works, but also expect a simple to do it, just like upload a word format file.

Comment: hi Alain, I have tried your proposal, it does work but not suit for me, In my situation, I need upload a image file into specific collection (directory) and do need convert it into google format in order to using Doc List Api retrieve it, as well as saving the storage usage.